# How can I find the week beginning date of a week number in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, week-number

I have a set of sales numbers and am trying to rank them by week.  The query works great, except that I end up with a week number.  How can I convert that week number to a beginning of week date?

```
SELECT 

SUM(`Sales`) `Record`,
Week(`DateTime of Sale`),
'Sales Record' AS `Category`,
'Weekly' AS `Interval`

FROM `SalesTable`

GROUP BY 
DATE(`DateTime of Sale`)

ORDER BY  SUM(`Sales`) DESC 

LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date

Comment: I have, but the problem that I run into with that one is that it relies on the weekbeginning of the year starting on a hypothetical Jan 1st, which it does not for this year or any of the previous recent years I am aware of.  So, if the year starts on Wednesday, then the solution to multiply by 7 to get the day number is off by three days.  Thanks for the link though! :)