# How to get month number in sql by passing the week number

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

This is my function as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION  getmonth
(        

 @startdate  datetime,@Week int
)        
RETURNS  int        
AS        
BEGIN                      
 declare @year int,@Month int;              
 declare @sdate  datetime=@startdate;       
 set @year= year(CAST(@startdate as date));  
 set @sdate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6,  '1/1/' + CAST( @year as varchar(4)) ) + (@Week-1) ,1);           
  SET @Month = month( @sdate);              
 return @month        

END
```

I Just want this function to return the month number when we pass a week number of the year and week start date of year.

Week should be start on Sunday and ends at Saturday.

Example

For Year 2015,Week start date is 12/28/2014.When we pass week number it should return the month number of year 2015.

Comment: So, for a given week number, you want to know in which month falls the Thursday of that week?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 1st week starts at 2015-01-01 (Or 1st of Jan each year) and you are using MySQL.

This query will return the Month number using the week.

```
select DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD('2015-01-01', INTERVAL 5 WEEK) ,'%m')
```

Here, in `2015-01-01` is starting date. In `INTERVAL 5 WEEK` the number `5` is the week number that you will provide

Result: `02` i.e. the second month of the year!

Using:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11423781/3578289

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: you should mention that you are assuming that OP wants this in mysql as the code above only works in mysql and not on sql server

Answer (score 0):

select now(),curdate(),curtime()

There is no current month or current week,but there is a query to know current date and time..
Use these example query shown below.

Example:-
CREATE TABLE getmonth
(
getmonthId int NOT NULL,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
getmonthDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
PRIMARY KEY (getmonthId)
)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005, you can use combination of DATEADD and DATEPART.  You can easily collapse it to single line of code, but this makes for easier readability.

```
declare @startdate datetime
  , @week int
  , @enddate datetime
  , @mo int

select @startdate = '12/28/2014', @week = 23
select @enddate = dateadd(wk, @week, @startdate)
select @mo = datepart(m, @enddate)

select @mo, @enddate
```