# Include date from week number in the following query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query that returns the top five weeks where the most questions were answered. The weeks are being returned by the number but I want the first date of the week instead of the number.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS answered, 
   Week(score_datetime) AS week, 
   Year(score_datetime) AS year 
FROM   development.score 
WHERE  score_datetime IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY Week(score_datetime) 
ORDER  BY answered DESC 
LIMIT  5;
```

My sql skills aren't the best so I am currently getting the date from the week number when returned with momentjs. So if anyone knows how I could include the date in the above query by what the week number and year is it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you select a (non-aggregated) column then in general you need to group by it too. So, YEAR(score_datetime) in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS answered, 
   Week(score_datetime) AS week,
   DATE_ADD(score_datetime, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(score_datetime)) DAY) as week_start,
   Year(score_datetime) AS year 
FROM   development.score 
WHERE  score_datetime IS NOT NULL 
GROUP  BY Week(score_datetime) 
ORDER  BY answered DESC 
LIMIT  5;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific question can be found at: [How to convert number of week into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date)

So, based on the answer the conversion formula is: `WEEKDAY(DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year, 1), INTERVAL Week(score_datetime) WEEK))`

Putting it together:

```
  SELECT Count(*) AS answered, 
DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(Year(score_datetime), 1), INTERVAL Week(score_datetime) WEEK) AS week, 
       Year(score_datetime) AS year 
    FROM   development.score 
    WHERE  score_datetime IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP  BY Week(score_datetime) 
    ORDER  BY answered DESC 
    LIMIT  5;
```