# How to use %U in str_to_date for MySQL

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I have a date stored for a weekly metric in a legacy database as a string with this format:

`2010 10` which was crafter with the `%Y %U` format (i.e years followed by week number)

So I try to reverse it into a datetime column by doing  `STR_TO_DATE(time_week, '%Y %U')` but it does not seem to understand the week format

when I do a test on hardcoded strings, it does not work too

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2015 01', '%Y %U');
+---------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2015 01', '%Y %U') |
+---------------------------------+
| 2015-00-00                      |
+---------------------------------+


mysql> select str_to_date('2015 20', '%Y %U');
+---------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2015 20', '%Y %U') |
+---------------------------------+
| 2015-00-00                      |
+---------------------------------+
```

I'm certainly missing the elephant in the room but I cant' see what.

Comment: in your dates ('2015 01' ) there is no have any day in this format so how it is possible to come any date from str_to_date function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dates, missing day so first of fall you should add any `day` in date. use the concat function to add day

```
CONCAT('2015 01', ' Sunday');
```

after this you should use the function `STR_TO_DATE()` and date format should be `'%X %V %W'` for above date(after `CONCAT()`)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015 01', ' Sunday'), '%X %V %W');
```

The output is `2015-01-04`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015 20', ' Sunday'), '%X %V %W');
```

Output is `2015-05-17`

I hope this will help you. 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date) post similar to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use format `"%X%V"` to convert a `year-week` string to a date because the combination of a year and week does not uniquely identify a year and month if the week crosses a month boundary. To convert a `year-week` to a date, you should also specify the `weekday`:

This is an example

```
select str_to_date('2015 20 Friday', '%X%V %W');
```

**EDIT**: Change `'%Y %U'` to `'%X%V %W'`