# Week day of week number in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause, dayofweek

I need to write a where clause that selects all records between Monday and Friday of a week number in a year. CURDATE() is not working as I'm not working with the current date, just the week number as reference.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the following:

```
WHERE appointment.appointment_date >= DATE(Monday of YEARWEEK(30)) and appointment.appointment_date <= DATE(Friday of YEARWEEK(30))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by using [DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). you can get all date that is not SUNDAY OR SATURDAY.

```
SELECT.... FROM appointment 
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(appointment.appointment_date) <> 1 
OR DAYOFWEEK(appointment.appointment_date) <> 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gives all dates that have a day of the week from Monday to Friday.

```
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(appointment.appointment_date) >= 2 AND DAYOFWEEK(appointment.appointment_date) <= 7
```

> DAYOFWEEK starts at 1 = Sunday

So use the above and the accepted answer of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date).

P.S. Dates are very complicated to do correctly, which calendar system are you using? UK / US / ISO? Is it a leap year? etc etc

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(appointment.appointment_date, '%w') in (1,2,3,4,5) and ATE_FORMAT(appointment.appointment_date, '%Y') = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Hear:1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 = Thursday, 5 = Friday