# How to convert month of week along day with difrerent fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, dayofweek, weekday

I have different fields with month week and day, i want to convert fields to date. Year is current year. The current table format and value's below.

**Current table**

```
----------------------------
| ID  | Month | Week | Day |
----------------------------
| 1   |  11   |  2   |  4  |
| 2   |  09   |  3   |  5  |
| 3   |  12   |  2   |  2  |
| 4   |  12   |  4   |  5  |
----------------------------
```

eg 3 record : year - 2018, Month - 11, Week - Second, Day - 2(Tuesday) 
convert into : **2018-11-05**.

**Output like below**

```
---------------------
| ID  |     Date    |
---------------------
|  1  |  2018-11-07 |
|  2  |  2018-09-06 |
|  3  |  2018-12-13 |
|  4  |  2018-12-29 |
---------------------

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(concat("2018",Month,Week(week))) from schedule
```

I tried the select query DAYOFWEEK and WEEK those only use for date. My process reverse.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `week` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Comment: How is 2018-09-06 in the third week of the ninth month?

Comment: And why 2018? You don't have a year column in your current table

Comment: I will get from current year..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert number of week into date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078730/how-to-convert-number-of-week-into-date)

Comment: May be not, because, they used week from year base like (33), but i create based on month base. first, second, third, four.

Comment: Can you share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` statement output?

Comment: Month 11 Week 2 Day 4 is 2018-11-07 ? Remind me how that works

Answer (score -1):

SQL takes the dates funny to the way we see them in the USA. 
YEARmonthDay all integers.
Hope this helps michael

Comment: Can you explain details.